# Best Way To Concatenate Strings In PHP With Spaces In Between

Tags: php, string, concatenation

I need to concatenate an indeterminate number of strings, and I would like a space in between two adjoining strings. Like so `a b c d e f`.

Also I do not want any leading or trailing spaces, what is the best way to do this in PHP?

Comment: How do you store those strings? Are they in an array? Or in separate variables?

Comment: They are separate variables, and if the vriable is not set or an empty string I do not want it included in the concatenated string.

Comment: @freshest And how are the variables generated? Can't you put the values in an array instead of free variables?

Comment: They come form a database and so some are NULL or empty strings.

Comment: 1- for the "best" in the title

Comment: Then just build the array of strings as you iterate the database rows and put the variables in the array only if they're not empty (then you can do the implode). Add that code here if you're unsure how to do it.

Comment: @freshest, you mean empty, not set.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You mean `$str = implode(' ', array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'));`?

Answer (score 6):

Simple way is:

```
$string="hello" . " " . "world";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$strings = array( " asd " , NULL, "", " dasd ", "Dasd  ", "", "", NULL );

function isValid($v){
return empty($v) || !$v ? false : true;
}

$concatenated = trim( implode( " ", array_map( "trim", array_filter( $strings, "isValid" ) ) ) );

//"asd dasd Dasd"
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function concatenate()
{
    $return = array();
    $numargs = func_num_args();
    $arg_list = func_get_args();
    for($i = 0; $i < $numargs; $i++)
    {
        if(empty($arg_list[$i])) continue;
        $return[] = trim($arg_list[$i]);
    }
    return implode(' ', $return);
}

echo concatenate("Mark ", " as ", " correct");
```

Answer (score 4):

I just want to add to deviousdodo's answer that if there is a case that there are empty strings in the array and you don't want these to appear in the concatenated string, such as "a,b,,d,,f" then it will better to use the following:

$str = implode(',', array_filter(array('a', 'b', '', 'd', '', 'f')));

Answer (score 2):

considering that you have all these strings collected into an array, a way to do it could be trough a foreach sentence like:

```
$res = "";
foreach($strings as $str) {
   $res.= $str." ";
}

if(strlen($res > 0))
    $res = substr($res,-1);
```

in this way you can have control over the process for future changes.

Comment: Sounds overkill when you have `implode()`.

Comment: yay, I know, but I usually like to have things opened and under control that gives me the freedom to make changes anytime when I'm facing unknown datatypes, cuz now it's an array of string but you never know what comes during the developing, so I like to have that kind of freedom. I always have time to change it to a simple implode / join as far as I'm sure about stuff.

Comment: Your solution (usage of `foreach`) assumes the strings are in an array. Usage of `implode` would also assume the strings are in an array. I don't see the freedom here, I only see a bunch of unnecessary lines which decrease readability.

Comment: that gives me the freedom to have a string of whatever objs and change the interiors of the statements in the loop, that's it. and this is just for prototyping issues, of course when u r sure, u get it right, so if it'll be an array of string obviously u choose a more fancy and less consuming solution like implode or join