# Print only the array values - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

I have the following code within a WP loop

```
<?php
                // Get the selected taxonomies for the post type
                $terms = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'course_type' );
                $classes = array();
                if ( $terms && ! is_wp_error( $terms ) ){
                    foreach ( $terms as $term) {
                        $classes[] = $term->slug;
                    }
                }
                ?>
```

What I am looking to do is print only the WP_Term object slug to use in the classes.

```
<div class="courses-search-result standout-box-shadow <?php print_r( $classes ); ?>">
```

Now, I have got it working to a point and printing a value in the classes - but it is also printing the array structure:

```
class="courses-search-result standout-box-shadow cilex-clearfix Array
(
    [0] => apprenticeship
)
"
```

Am I close to getting the correct code with my PHP? My knowledge of the language is basic right now so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best Way To Concatenate Strings In PHP With Spaces In Between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8068428/best-way-to-concatenate-strings-in-php-with-spaces-in-between)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`print_r` is a function intended for debugging, not formatted output.

The simplest way to achieve what you want is using [`implode`](http://php.net/implode), which combines the values of an array into a string; and then [`echo`](http://php.net/echo) to display the string.

```
<div class="courses-search-result standout-box-shadow <?php echo implode(' ', $classes); ?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) combined with a [PHP short echo tag](http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php) (i.e. `<?=` - available in PHP 5.4+ or earlier with the [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) configuration setting enabled):

```
<div class="courses-search-result standout-box-shadow <?= implode(' ', $classes ); ?>">
```